# How to use a method object (which is in the class) outside the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, class

I have a method object with assigned value from user's input inside a class. The problem is i can't use  the method object `maxcount_inventory = int(input("How many Inventories: "))` outside the class. The error says "`method' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`"

```
class CLASS_INVENTORY:
    maxcount_inventory = int(input("How many Inventories: "))
    inventory_name = []
    def __init__(Function_Inventory):
        for count_inventory in range(Function_Inventory.maxcount_inventory): 
            add_inventory = str(input("Enter Inventory #%d: " % (count_inventory+1)))
            Function_Inventory.inventory_name.append(add_inventory)

    def Return_Inventory(Function_Inventory):
        return Function_Inventory.inventory_name

    def Return_Maxcount(Function_Inventory):
        return maxcount_inventory

maxcount_inventory = CLASS_INVENTORY().Return_Maxcount
```

Another extra question if I may, how can i access items in the list per index outside the class? I have the code below, but I think it's not working. Haven't found out yet due to my error above.

```
for count_inventory in range(maxcount_inventory):
    class_inv = CLASS_INVENTORY().Return_Inventory[count_inventory]
    print(class_inv)
    skip()
```

Here is my full code: https://pastebin.com/crnayXYy

Comment: You forgot to provide parameters for return_maxcount with maxcount_inventory variable

Comment: Why have you used the name `Function_Inventory` for the parameters to the methods? It is an almost inviolable standard to use `self`, if you do otherwise you'll confuse yourself and anyone reading your code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I see. Okay, i'll switch to 'self'.

Comment: @mgracer How do i provide the parameters?

Comment: You don't need a parameter, you need to actually *call* the method: `CLASS_INVENTORY().Return_Maxcount()`.

Comment: Return_Maxcount() just add that to CLASS_INVENTORY(), didn't know you were using self. you even confused me LOL

Comment: Okay, new error displayed after applying your fix. It says "maxcount_inventory is not defined"

Comment: Because it should be `self.maxcount_inventory`.

Comment: Thank you. It ran, but it looped and asked me twice, then method object error reappeared saying it's not subscriptable. I don't know what's going on. I'm sorry, just new in Python 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go I've refactored your code.

As @Daniel Roseman mentioned you should be using `self` rather than `Function_Inventory`, so I changed that. I also changed the return value of `Return_Maxcount` to provide a list as you requested.

```
class CLASS_INVENTORY:
    maxcount_inventory = int(input("How many Inventories: "))
    inventory_name = []
    def __init__(self):
        for count_inventory in range(self.maxcount_inventory): 
            add_inventory = str(input("Enter Inventory #%d: " % (count_inventory+1)))
            self.inventory_name.append(add_inventory)

    def Return_Inventory(self):
        for item in self.inventory_name:
            print(item)

    def Return_Maxcount(self):
        return self.inventory_name

maxcount_inventory = CLASS_INVENTORY()
inventory_list = maxcount_inventory.Return_Maxcount()
maxcount_inventory.Return_Inventory()
```

You can change the print statement at the bottom and set that equal to a variable to access it outside of the class itself.

Comment: Thank you so much you guys are awesome! How about if I want to print all my inventory names?

Comment: you have to make a for loop to do so

Comment: @Geni-sama I added a for loop at the bottom for you. Now it will print the full list followed by each individual item

Comment: Yes, I also accept this answer, as the code in the question has no use of self which is not a good sign for OOPS concept.

Comment: THANK YOU GUYS SO MUCH. I LEARNED FEW THINGS BECAUSE OF YOU ALL. I'M SO HAPPY TODAY. (SORRY FOR THE CAPS)

Comment: Cheers :) I edited the `for` loop into the function and then called that. Just cleans it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In your code just change this:

```
maxcount_inventory = CLASS_INVENTORY().Return_Maxcount
```

to this:

```
maxcount_inventory = CLASS_INVENTORY().Return_Maxcount()
```

also change the variables in your class to have the self. prefix before them
like `self.maxcount_inventory`
the reason is you want to call your method , otherwise it will try getting a variable not the method.
you also want to change all your arguments in your functions inside of the class to self